# strange binomial coefficient transformation, Equation 41 at MacKay Information theory book

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, approximation, information-theory

The top equation is very clear, but how is the first approximation done? The author mentions this line as an alternative to Stirling's approximation. It should be a straightforward equation, but sorry I could not get it

Thank you in advance!

$$
\begin{split}
1 &= \sum_K \binom{N}{K}2^{-N} \\
  &\approx 2^{-N} \binom{N}{N/2} \sum_{r=-N/2}^{N/2} e^{-(r/\sigma)^2/2}\\
  &\approx 2^{-N} \binom{N}{N/2} \sigma \sqrt{2\pi}.
\end{split}
$$

Answer (score 0):

The last approximation comes because for large $N$,
$$
\sum_{r=-N/2}^{N/2} e^{-(r/\sigma)^2/2}
\approx \int_\mathbb{R} e^{-(r/\sigma)^2/2} dr
 = \sigma \int_\mathbb{R} e^{-u^2/2} du
 = \sigma\sqrt{2\pi}
$$
where $u = r/\sigma$ and the last step is a famous Gaussian integral, which can be taken, e.g., by switching to polar coordinates...

Comment: Thank you, but my question is about the first approximation where the binomial coefficient is transformed into exponential